# I followed ReactNative docs to build AwesomeProject iOS target but encountered a problem while building tvOS

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, tvos

I followed the link below to install new reactNative App ..

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

After Successfully Installed I am able to run the iOS target but not tvOS while running tvOS I am getting below error ..

**Library not found for -lPods-AwesomeProject-tvOS** Are there any additional steps to follow to setup tvos Target to up and running.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried this link? [Building for TV Devices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv)

Comment: have you installed tvOs package with cocoa pod?

Comment: @MinhDao Thanks for the reply but I don't even have the platform.ios.js at all

Comment: @mohsen.h I am using cocoapods and when i check the pod file it has all pods included in iOS target so I added the same pods for tvos except this one React-RCTActionSheet bcz it is not for tvos but still I am getting errors and it still building that pod after I excluded for tvos..

Comment: @mohsen.h added other question about this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940703/my-react-native-encountered-a-problem-while-building-tvos-but-ios-succeeded